# javascript: is object.seal(class) combined with object.seal(class.prototype) sufficient?

Tags: javascript, web-services, web-applications

is Object.seal(Class) combined with Object.seal(Class.prototype) sufficient to "protect" my class from abuse?

this is my class:

```
var Lazy;
(function(){
  var value;
  var value_exists=false;
  var init;
  Lazy=function(_init){
    init=_init;
  };
  Lazy.prototype={get V(){
                    if(!value_exists){
                      value=init();
                      value_exists=true;
                    }
                    return value;
                  },set V(_value){
                    value=_value;
                    value_exists=true;
                  }};
  Object.seal(Lazy);Object.seal(Lazy.prototype);
})();
```

It works like this, my code run first. then i grab a mashup's code (possibly generated dynamically) and run. problem is i can't tell if the mashup is friendly or dirty. so i'm protecting my script against his script which i took and run after my code has run first.

he probably isn't a "real attacker". but if he messed up my code chances are the app will throw an exception and stop running.. not something i want my users to experience. Hence this question is important to me.

I understand that the user can hack the source code since nothing on the client side is safe. But for this question we can assume the user here is not an attacker. My purpose is clear: I do not want my users to experience exceptions while using the site (due to those mashups that I've included in my site). If the user himself is an attacker, I've got no problems letting him experience all the funny things, its his own problem anyway.

What I'm worried, are the code in the mashups. (my website does not allow users to inject any code, but a mashup can do that)

Comment: I don't get sealing classes. If an attacker wanted to do stuff to it, he would've just removed the Object.seal and run it again. JavaScript can't really have immutable because its code is so wide open.

Comment: JavaScript is client-side and open source. Any security should be done on the server. This is pseudo-security and useless againts a real attack.

Comment: So why do it if it's useless?

Comment: @Zirak to stop developers using your library from accidentally extending objects. This only helps developers not make mistakes

Comment: btw i've edited the question. there was a bug with the code previously

Comment: @Zirak it works like this, my code run first. then i grab a mashup's code and run. problem is i can't tell if the mashup is friendly or dirty. so i'm protecting my script against his script which i took and run after my code has run first. he probably isn't a "real attacker". but if he messed up my code chances are the app will throw an exception and stop running.. not something i want my users to experience

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.freeze(Lazy);
Object.freeze(Lazy.prototype);
```

[Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) is Object.seal and then some; it also makes the existing properties non-writable (see [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/).) That's as hardcore as you can get. But still useless as a real protection mechanism.

Comment: heys may you comment on why its useless as a real protection mechanism? (btw i've updated the question slightly)

Comment: @Pacerier - `freeze` seems fine runtime (meaning, from trying to poke it with a stick it behaved as expected), however, a real protection works in 100% of the situations 100% of the time, and there's nothing to stop a user, who is also an attacker, from changing the source code on the fly, removing your protection mechanism. That's why you also never trust something which came from a client-side filter - you can never assumed it ran.

Comment: @Zirak Ok we can assume the user here is not an attacker. I do not want my users to experience exceptions while using the site (Because if he is an attacker I've no problems letting him experience the exceptions, its his own problem anyway)

Comment: @Zirak I'm saying those mashups which I'm afraid of (that they have purposeful or mis-purposeful trouble-code)

Comment: @Pacerier First, the user is always an attacker. Second, your code can never be perfect. Third, what happens on a browser that doesn't have ES5? `Object.freeze` doesn't exist. Fourth, why are you using 3rd party code which you do not trust?

Comment: @Zirak Sorry if I'm not clear. My purpose is clear: I do not want my users to experience exceptions while using the site (due to those mashups that I've included in my site). If the user himself is an attacker, I've got no problems letting him experience all the funny things, its his own problem anyway.

Comment: @Zirak see my updated question. If a browser does not have ES5 I'm rejecting him out. If he's a hacker and manage to hack through that I'm fine. (he will just get all the exceptions in his face, he can't really hack any data-related stuff just because he managed to alter the source code in anyway he likes)

Comment: @Zirak I trust the third-party. But people do make mistakes, a code with error is a dangerous piece of code, and also, if they get hacked, I do not wish to be affected just because of their mistake.

Comment: Answer remains the same. (client-side) JavaScript is unsecure by nature, having open code. Real security cannot be achieved via js because of the above. Your users will experience bugs because a piece of code can never be perfect. So, answer remains: If you want a blanky to protect you from the evil monsters, use `Object.freeze`

Comment: @Zirak you seem to miss my point. what i want is not security. what i want is a better user experience

Comment: @Pacerier Answer remains the same. No matter what you do, whatever quack technique you use to protect yourself from bugs, your program will have them. As said, you can use a blanky if you wish, but you'll be using it for the wrong reason.

Comment: @zirak what if I want to load untrusted third-part plugins?

Comment: @janesconference That's a bad idea to begin with, and the 3rd party plugins putting gremlins in your object would be the least of your worries. And that's why [ADSafe](http://www.adsafe.org/) was made.